# Identify duplicate records and update a flag on them

Tags: oracle, duplicates

There is a table - let's call it `DemoReport` - with below set of keys.

- `YearOfGeneration`
- `WeekOfGeneration`
- `Key3`
- `Key4`

There is one more column for a flag denoting the latest record. This column is not part of key. If this flag is true, the particular record is the latest one.
When the record gets created through code, by default this flag is set to true.

Sample record should look like:

```
    | *YearOfGeneration* | *WeekOfGeneration* | *Key3*        | *Key4*      | *Latest*
    | 2017               | 2                  | Key3Sample1   | Key4Sample1 | 1
    | 2017               | 3                  | Key3Sample1   | Key4Sample1 | 1
```

Any record should be marked as latest when `Key3` and `Key4` are same, and `YearOfGeneration` and `WeekOfGeneration` should be the latest. So in above example, second record should have latest flag set to true and first should have it false.

Requirement is to write a sql which will identify and update records to unset the 'latest' flag on records which are not latest.

Can someone please suggest how should the sql be written?

Comment: Why would you ever want to store information on which row is the latest in the table itself? This should be part of some view or a query that finds the "latest" row (depending on business requirements); we usually do not store aggregated results in a table in OLTP systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE DemoReport 
SET latest = 0 -- Whatever older record should be marked as 
WHERE 
(YearOfGeneration ||LPAD(WeekOfGeneration,2,'0')|| Key3||Key4) 
NOT IN 
(SELECT 
MAX(YearOfGeneration || LPAD(WeekOfGeneration,2,'0'))|| Key3 || Key4
FROM DemoReport
GROUP BY Key3, Key4);

Commit;
```

Comment: And how will this work if max week of generation for year 2016 is 10, and max week of generation for year 2017 is 6 (obviously for the same key3 and key4)?

Comment: Thanks for writing this answer. Yes I agree, this solution works in general scenarios where all weeks belong to same year. But when one record has week number as 52, year as 2017 and the other record has week number as 1 and year as 2018. Can you suggest probable solution for this?

Comment: It should work on that scenario as well since the the query will exclude max value between 201752 and 201801 (LPAD will add 0) for the same grouping of Key3 and Key4. It will exclude the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `row_number ()` to get the valid records and a merge statement to update corresponding records.

```
MERGE INTO DemoReport m
     USING (SELECT d.*,
                   CASE
                      WHEN     ROW_NUMBER ()
                               OVER (
                                  PARTITION BY key3, key4
                                  ORDER BY
                                     YearOfGeneration DESC,WeekOfGeneration DESC) !=
                                  1
                           AND LATEST = 1
                      THEN
                         0
                      ELSE
                         LATEST
                   END
                      new_latest
              FROM DemoReport d) s
        ON (    m.key3 = s.key3
            AND m.key4 = s.key4
            AND m.WeekOfGeneration = s.WeekOfGeneration)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET m.latest = s.new_latest;
```

Comment: Why concatenation of YearOfGeneration and WeekOfGeneration? It won't work correctly if there are, for instance, weeks 2 and 11 in the table. I presume you wanted to join on all four key columns, not only three.

Comment: @GoranStefanović : Thanks , I forgot to add  `TO_NUMBER`  However the problem still is that If the OP is using week1,week2, week3 ...week52 for 2017 , only then it will  work . But if it is week1..week4,week1,week2.... it will not. The op needs to clarify it.

Comment: I wouldn't use any conversion at all - it would be enough to do ORDER BY YearOfGeneration DESC, WeekOfGeneration DESC. I agree that OP should clarify how WeekOfGeneration is populated - based on the question my assumption is that it will be 1..52 per year

Comment: @GoranStefanović : Oh Yes. They could should  be numbers after all. Thanks anyway for pointing it. I was over generalizing.